# Does resizing the browser window(using inspect-Devtools) resize the content included?

Tags: css

I have just started to learn Web-development. So I would be glad to get this silly doubt sorted out.

In the following CSS-code

```
{
background-color: grey;
}

.container {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width:100%;
min-height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

A div element of class"container" is created. I have given min-height in the idea that when the browser window is expanded, the container will also expand since the min-height:150px is present. But the container element remains of the same height(150px) irrespective of the expanding browser!

[I have added the output image along with dev-tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdyHM.png)

Comment: i can't really understand your question . Can you please make a working example ?

Comment: that div will only grow if the content grow, and since it is an image, it won't expand like you are thinking. Images have a fixed height, unless it is a vectorial image

Comment: You told your `div` to be at least 150 pixels tall, and that's exactly what it does, did you maybe confuse absolute vs. relative units?

Comment: Does expanding the browser window make the div element (container) to exceed 150px? @Lars Beck

Comment: Please take a look at the image. When the browser is resized, the div element (in blue) remains 150px height rather than expanding. @Mihai

Comment: why would it expand ? the div only expands depending on it's content. so if it doesn't have content inside. it won't expand. rules of css. Heigh of div can be set by 3 different things ( in general ) :  height, min-height and the height of content inside. So in your case, it will always have 150px height ( if it doesn't have any content inside it that would make it increase in height )

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks a lot, Mihai.  Now I get it!